# How to purge deleted documents from Lotus Domino application

Tags: lotus-domino

I am working with a vendor to debug an issue with a Lotus Domino 6.5 application. The vendor had originally asked me to make a copy of the application by going to File > Database > New Copy > Design Only, and then to copy some sample documents (with sensitive info removed) from the original database to the new database. But when I copy documents in this way, the views do not display correctly.

I then tried making a copy of the application by going to File > Database > New Copy > Design and Documents, and then deleting all but a few documents. When I copy documents in this way, the views display correctly, but the database size is huge, which makes me think that the original documents have not really been deleted. For privacy reasons, all deleted documents need to be unrecoverable.

My question: How can I purge documents that have been marked for deletion in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While in the database, choose **File - Application - Properties** from the menu, click the last tab (the propeller-hat) and deselect these two database properties if they are selected:

- "Don't overwrite free space" - Obviously you want to overwrite the free space.
- "Allow Soft Deletions" - Deselecting this will purge any documents that are deleted but recoverable.

Once you've done that, choose **File - Replication - Options for this Application...**, click the "Other" tab, and change the date/time to the current date/time. This gets rid of the "deletion stubs" which remain for a time so that, if replication occurs with a different machine, that machine learns that the document was deleted rather than telling yours "Oh! Here's a brand new document!" This is completely unnecessary unless you want to ensure that even the count or internal ids of deleted documents are removed. The actual content will be gone.

After that, compact the database because you'll have free space or, if you want to be really paranoid, create a copy of *your copy*.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I did any Lotus Notes development, but you can [compact the database](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTWP_9.0.1/com.ibm.notes901.help.doc/app_compact_a_notesapp_t.html).

> 1. Open a database.
> 2. Choose File - Database - Properties.
> 3. Click the Info tab.
> 4. Click % used.
> 5. If the percentage of a database in use drops below 90% (it contains more than 10% unused space), click Compact to compact the database.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify,  my issue is not the database size per se, but the persistence of documents with sensitive data. For privacy reasons, all deleted documents need to be unrecoverable. Will compacting the database do this?